# Dropdown-menu visible outside parent-element that has overflow: auto

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a table that is very wide.
This is why I have a scrollbar on the table both on the X-axis and Y-axis.

```
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: scroll;
```

In a cell inside the table, I put a dropdown-menu.
This works perfectly.
BUT if I open the dropdown-menu for a row far down, the dropdown is hidden behind the end of the table and I have to scroll down to see it.
I can make this visible by making the table css

```
 overflow: visible;
```

But then I lose my scrollbars on the table.
Is there a way to make the dropdown show even if I have scrollbars?

Comment: You should post the html and css.

Comment: We need to see how that dropdown is created. And also the table. We cannot help you if we are in the "dark"

Comment: try setting max-width:100%; to dropdown menu.. hope this helps

Comment: can you fiddle here?

Answer (score -1):

Try with The z-index property, It specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). Default value: auto.

[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex)